# How can I write XMP metadata to a QuickTime video on iOS?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, metadata, quicktime, xmp

I’m trying to attach some XMP metadata to a QuickTime video I'm exporting using `AVAssetExportSession`.

AVFoundation does support writing metadata (`AVMetadataItem`) and I’ve managed to export simple values which can subsequently be examined using [exiftool](https://exiftool.org):

```
AVMutableMetadataItem *item = [AVMutableMetadataItem metadataItem];
item.identifier = [AVMetadataItem identifierForKey:AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle keySpace:AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon];
item.value = @"My Title";

exportSession.metadata = @[item];
```

But I’m having trouble configuring my `AVMetadataItem`’s to correctly encode XMP. According to the [Adobe XMP spec](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/XMP%20SDK%20Release%20cc-2016-08/XMPSpecificationPart3.pdf), XMP in QuickTime videos should be under the `moov` / `udta` / `XMP_` atoms but I can’t see a way to make hierarchical metadata using the AVFoundation API, or any key space that corresponds to this part of the metadata.

I also need to write XMP metadata to images, and Image I/O does have direct support for this (`CGImageMetadataCreateFromXMPData`), but I can't find anything equivalent in AVFoundation.

If it's not possible using AVFoundation (or similar), I'll probably look at integrating [XMP-Toolkit-SDK](https://github.com/adobe/XMP-Toolkit-SDK) but this feels like a clunky solution when AVFoundation *almost* seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to figure this after trying lots of variations of keys/key spaces and other attributes of `AVMetadataItem`:

- Use a custom `XMP_` key in the `AVMetadataKeySpaceQuickTimeUserData` key space
- Set the value not as an `NSString` but as an `NSData` containing UTF-8 data for the payload
- Set the `dataType` to raw data

This results in XMP attributes that can be read by exiftool as expected.

```swift
NSString *payload =
  @"<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x=\"adobe:ns:meta/\" x:xmptk=\"MyAppXMPLibrary\">"
    "<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#\">"
      "<rdf:Description rdf:about=\"\" xmlns:xmp=\"http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/\">"
        "<xmp:CreatorTool>My App</xmp:CreatorTool>"
      "</rdf:Description>"
    "</rdf:RDF>"
  "</x:xmpmeta>";

NSData *data = [payload dataUsingEncoding:kCFStringEncodingUTF8];

AVMutableMetadataItem *item = [AVMutableMetadataItem metadataItem];
item.identifier = [AVMetadataItem identifierForKey:@"XMP_"
                                          keySpace:AVMetadataKeySpaceQuickTimeUserData];
item.dataType = (NSString *)kCMMetadataBaseDataType_RawData;
item.value = data;

exportSession.metadata = @[item];
```